# Unable to Automatically Start Html5Qrcode (html5-qrcode) Scanner After Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I am using the Html5Qrcode scanner in a WordPress plugin to scan product barcodes. My workflow is as follows:

1.Start the Html5Qrcode scanner and scan a barcode.

2.Use the decoded barcode value to search for and display information about a product in a form.

3.After the user updates the form and clicks "Submit", an AJAX call is made to process the form data.

4.Upon successful form submission, I want to automatically restart the Html5Qrcode scanner so that the user can scan the next product.

However, I'm unable to successfully restart the scanner after form submission. The scanner works perfectly when started manually using a button click event. The issue occurs only when I attempt to start the scanner programmatically in the AJAX success callback.

I have defined the scanner start process as a separate JavaScript function, which I call both on the button click event and in the AJAX success callback.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```js
function startScanner() {
  // Show the scanner and hide the product info
  $('#reader').show();
  $('#product_info').hide();

  if (qrreader == null) {
    qrreader = new Html5Qrcode(qrreaderElementId);
    const videoConstraints = {
      facingMode: "environment"
    };

    const config = {
      fps: 10,
      qrbox: {
        width: 250,
        height: 250
      }
    };

    let isWaitingForResponse = false;
    const qrCodeSuccessCallback = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
      if (isWaitingForResponse) {
        console.log("Still waiting for the previous scan...");
        return;
      }

      isWaitingForResponse = true;

      console.log(`Message: ${decodedText}, Result: ${JSON.stringify(decodedResult)}`);
      $('#barcode_search').val(decodedText); // Set the value of the barcode field
      $("#barcode_submit").trigger('click'); // Trigger a click event on the submit button

      // Hide the scanner and show the product info
      $('#reader').hide();
      $('#product_info').show();

      // Set a timeout to allow the next scan
      setTimeout(() => {
        isWaitingForResponse = false;
      }, 5000); // 5000ms = 5 seconds, adjust as needed
    };
    const qrCodeErrorCallback = (errorMessage) => {
      console.log(errorMessage);
    };

    qrreader.start(
      videoConstraints,
      config,
      qrCodeSuccessCallback,
      qrCodeErrorCallback
    ).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}

// Start scanner on button click
$(document).on('click', '#start_reader', function() {
  startScanner();
});

// Start scanner after successful form submission
$('#update_form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../my-scanner-script.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        // Attempt to start the scanner
        startScanner();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Despite no errors being thrown in the console, the scanner does not restart after form submission. I have verified that the startScanner function is indeed being called in the AJAX success callback.

I suspect this might be due to browser restrictions on autoplaying media streams without a direct user action. If this is the case, is there any workaround that allows the scanner to restart programmatically?

Any help or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe try setting `qrreader = null;`  before calling `startScanner();` again

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*(Considering some of the variables are clearly missing from the question's code snippet)*</sub>

Seems like this code is running only if a `global` variable `qrreader`

***Problem***

```js
function startScanner() {
  // ... 

  if (qrreader == null) {
    qrreader = new Html5Qrcode(qrreaderElementId);
    // ...
  }
}
```

if you call again `startScanner` qrreader *will* be an Object instance and the `if` statement will not run.

***Possible solution:***

```js
let qrreader = null;

function startScanner() {
  // ... 

  if (!qrreader) qrreader = new Html5Qrcode(qrreaderElementId);

  // ...
}
```

---

Also, there's a potential issue that you're not clearing properly your timeouts. Clear them like:

```js
let waitingTimeout;

function startScanner() {
  clearTimeout(waitingTimeout);

  // ... 

  waitingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    isWaitingForResponse = false;
  }, 5000);

  // ...
}
```

For completeness, here's a slight remake that uses a single instance without any checks and uses no timeouts:

```html
<button id="start_reader">Start QR Code scanner</button>

<form id="update_form">
  <div id="reader"></div>
  <input id="barcode_search" />
  <button id="barcode_submit">Submit</button>
  <div id="product_info">Some product info</div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html5-qrcode" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```js
// Create a QR code reader instance
const qrReader = new Html5Qrcode("reader");

// QR reader settings
const qrConstraints = {
  facingMode: "environment"
};
const qrConfig = {
  fps: 10,
  qrbox: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250
  }
};
const qrOnSuccess = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
  stopScanner(); // Stop the scanner
  console.log(`Message: ${decodedText}, Result: ${JSON.stringify(decodedResult)}`);
  $("#barcode_search").val(decodedText); // Set the value of the barcode field
  $("#update_form").trigger("submit"); // Submit form to backend
};

// Methods: start / stop
const startScanner = () => {
  $("#reader").show();
  $("#product_info").hide();
  qrReader.start(
    qrConstraints,
    qrConfig,
    qrOnSuccess,
  ).catch(console.error);
};

const stopScanner = () => {
  $("#reader").hide();
  $("#product_info").show();
  qrReader.stop().catch(console.error);
};

// Start scanner on button click
$(document).on("click", "#start_reader", function() {
  startScanner();
});

// Submit 
$("#update_form").on("submit", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../my-scanner-script.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status === "success") {
        // Attempt to start the scanner
        startScanner();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: fwiw, I would suggest creating a seperate `restartScanner()` function that resets the scanner, clears timeouts, etc. and then calls start scanner again...

Comment: @lemonskunnk edited with a full working example

Comment: Tried it exactly like you said. Unfortunately script is incredibly stubborn and will not budge. I ripped out the ajax part, and started over. I hope I will get it running this way. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The script I provided worked pretty well for me. I was using i.e: NodeJS instead of PHP, but my Express server got the request. And everything worked just fine.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot!